# Rails 7 view and direct upload image from browser client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

It's been a long time since I've used Rails for the frontend of a web app, and I want to use the most update version of course, but it seems a lot has changed and I don't know which is the most Rails Way to do it anymore.

I've tried to use JQuery and the FileUpload plugin, but we don't have JQuery anymore, I mean I've tried to add it but it was a pain in the ass using the new import map (problem with me, I know if I look up some tutorials I can do i), but that seems to go agains the current mentality of JS in rails apps.

Then I've went to checkout the new Hotwire + Stimulus but I don't even now where to start, but from the little that I saw don't know if will handle this scenario: **I already have a `presigned_url` from my `S3 Bucket`, and simply have a form with a `f.file_field` which I want to upload this file from the clients browser directly to `S3` doing a `POST` request, so the user don't get blocked waiting the upload to finish**

Correct me if I'm wrong but to trigger JS functions the Rails Way now is to use `Stimulus` with `HTML Data Attributes` but I'm not sure if I could pass the file in this data attribute.

Looking other tutorials I'm starting to think that the best approach would be to have a `turbo_stream_tag` to wrap my form, and then when submitting the form will hit this turbo controller which will act as a ajax request, running asynchronously doing a post request using `Net:HTTP` or even the `s3` gem itself, I'm just not sure if I would have access to the file.

Any kind soul to clarify this? Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably want to look at this if you haven't: *https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#example*

Here is a starter with default Rails 7 setup with importmaps. Mostly taken from example link above and wrapped in Stimulus.

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

pin "@rails/activestorage", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/activestorage@7.0.2/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.esm.js"
```

```html
<!-- inside your form -->
<div data-controller="upload">
  <%= form.file_field :avatar, direct_upload: true,
    data: { upload_target: "input",
            action:        "change->upload#uploadFile" } %>
  <div data-upload-target="progress"></div>
</div>
```

This will start uploading as soon as file is selected. With *Turbo* it is non blocking. As long as the browser is not refreshed it will be uploading.

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/upload_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input", "progress"];

  uploadFile() {
    Array.from(this.inputTarget.files).forEach((file) => {
      const upload = new DirectUpload(
        file,
        this.inputTarget.dataset.directUploadUrl,
        this // callback directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request)
      );
      upload.create((error, blob) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          this.createHiddenBlobInput(blob);
          // if you're not submitting the form after upload, you need to attach
          // uploaded blob to some model here and skip hidden input.
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // add blob id to be submitted with the form
  createHiddenBlobInput(blob) {
    const hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id);
    hiddenField.name = this.inputTarget.name;
    this.element.appendChild(hiddenField);
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request) {
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
      this.progressUpdate(event);
    });
  }

  progressUpdate(event) {
    const progress = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    this.progressTarget.innerHTML = progress;

    // if you navigate away from the form, progress can still be displayed 
    // with something like this:
    // document.querySelector("#global-progress").innerHTML = progress;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Soooooo, sorry for the delay just got into this, the easiest and most forward way of implementing active storage direct upload, it's pretty simple although the docs are not really clear about how to achieve it with Stimulus. So if you follow [this docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#example) and you want to make it work with Stimulus make sure to override the javascript with this section, first, create the Stimulus controller, add event listeners for the actions you want, in my example, it would be `onDrop` and `onChange` event and then bind it with the custom uploader class that we will create.

```js
// rails generate stimulus direct_uploads
// => creates a js file under app/javascript/controllers/direct_uploads_controller.js

import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

// don't worry about this import you'll find the class right below
import Uploader from '../utils/direct_uploads';

// Connects to data-controller="direct-uploads"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
  }

  // drop->direct-uploads#handleInputChange
  handleOnDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { files } = event.dataTransfer;
    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => this.uploadFile(file));
  }

  // change->direct-uploads#handleInputChange
  handleInputChange({ currentTarget }) {
    const { files } = currentTarget;
    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => this.uploadFile(file, currentTarget));
  }

  uploadFile(file, currentTarget) {
    const upload = new Uploader(file, currentTarget);
    upload.start();
  }
}

// now let's create the uploader class.
// => app/javascript/utils/direct_uploads.js

import { DirectUpload } from '@rails/activestorage';

export default class Uploader {
  constructor(file, currentTarget) {
    const { dataset: { directUploadUrl } } = currentTarget;

    this.directUpload = new DirectUpload(file, directUploadUrl, this);
    this.targetForm = currentTarget.closest('form');
    this.file = file;
    this.currentTarget = currentTarget;
  }

  start() {
    this.directUpload.create((error, blob) => {
      if (error) {
        // Handle the error
      } else {
        // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form
        // with a value of blob.signed_id
      }
    });
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request) {
    request.upload.addEventListener(
      'progress',
      (event) => this.directUploadDidProgress(event),
    );
  }

  directUploadDidProgress(event) {
    // Use event.loaded and event.total to update the progress bar
  }
}
```

let me know if you know a better way to do it, without using any extra libraries