# Rails 7 ActiveStorage DirectUpload to S3 presigned_url return 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

So I was able to set up the direct upload on the view, and send a request to the `s3_presigned_url` that I've created. The problem is: I'm getting a `403 Forbidden`.

My main guess on the issue is about the request method that is being made, with is a `POST` and in fact should be a `PUT`, also I do believe that there are some header missing/wrong like the `Content-Type` and `Content-MD5`

I've followed the Rails Tutorial and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632824/rails-7-view-and-direct-upload-image-from-browser-client/71634352#71634352) , here's my code

*presigned_url*
`3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object(upload_key)..presigned_url(:put,{ acl: 'public-read' })`

*form.html.erb*

```
<%= form.file_field :image, direct_upload: true, data: { upload_target: 'input', action: "change->upload#uploadFile", direct_upload_url: @presigned_url } %>
```

Note that I've change the `direct-upload-url` from `/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads` not sure if this was right? but it was the only way to send this to this presigned url, not sure if there is a way to specify the bucket and file path otherwise

*upload_controller.js*

```js
// app/javascripts/controllers/upload_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input", "progress"];

  uploadFile() {
    Array.from(this.inputTarget.files).forEach((file) => {
      const upload = new DirectUpload(
        file,
        this.inputTarget.dataset.directUploadUrl,
        this // callback directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request)
      );
      upload.create((error, blob) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          this.createHiddenBlobInput(blob);
          // if you're not submitting a form after upload. you need to attach
          // uploaded blob to some model here and skip hidden input.
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // add blob id to be submitted with the form
  createHiddenBlobInput(blob) {
    const hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id);
    hiddenField.name = this.inputTarget.name;
    this.element.appendChild(hiddenField);
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request) {
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
      this.progressUpdate(event);
    });
  }

  progressUpdate(event) {
    const progress = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    this.progressTarget.innerHTML = progress;

    // if you navigate away from the form, progress can still be displayed 
    // with something like this:
    // document.querySelector("#global-progress").innerHTML = progress;
  }
}
```

*Request Headers*

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 118
Content-Type: application/json
Host: *my_bucket_url*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token: uYpbxLFUaApHXl00j_qWXbQOgjTUTMgx33nmBr2Xh4NYKC5yD6t1F6bIAN-lX5FpKd-Yx2hBDD64DtFmf7UI3A
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

And the error `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

`UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`

Not sure how to set the correct headers in this upload to S3.

**UPDATE:**
Correctly configured the `store.yml` with my AWS credentials, and used the default direct upload url, ActiveStorage was able to upload the file, but it does at a random key on the roof of the bucket, from what I've read there's no way to set the `key` of the upload so this won't work, will look another solution